# SelectionHelper.getSelectedObjectinOutline() returns null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop eclipse plugin in which i want to read data from a selected file of package explorer or outline window. In my plugin i am using SelectionHelper.getSelectedObjectinOutline() method for this purpose.I run plugin as eclipse application. Despite selecting file SelectionHelper.getSelectedObjectinOutline() method returns null.

Comment: What is `SelectionHelper`? It isn't part of core Eclipse.

Comment: org.osate.ui.utils.SelectionHelper

Comment: Assuming that is [this code](https://github.com/osate/osate2-core/blob/develop/org.osate.ui/src/org/osate/ui/utils/SelectionHelper.java) it only provides the selection for the outline of an Xtext based editor. Most editors are not based on Xtext and this is nothing to do with Package Explorer. [edit] your question and provide more details about what you are trying to do.